# Prevent frame scrolling when screen is too small

Tags: html, css, frame

I'm using frames. My logo frame contains 2 pictures. One is 150px and other 600px making the whole logo size of 750px. Now, when user is making the window smaller than whole number then my second picture is being scrolled down without ability to see the picture.

The easiest possible way would be to connect 2 pictures into one 750px one, but is there a way to avoid this?

All I have as a code on my logo frame is...

```
<body class="logo_background">
    <img src="assets/logo.png">
    <img src="assets/logo_name.png">
</body>
```

my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Portfolio</title>
</head>
<frameset rows="80px,100%" cols="*" framespacing="0" frameborder="no" border="0">
  <frame src="logo.html" name="logo" scrolling="no">
  <frameset rows="*" cols="150,100%">
    <frame src="menu.html" name="menu" scrolling="no">
    <frame src="main_page.html" name="page" scrolling="no">
  </frameset>
</frameset>
<noframes><body>
</body></noframes>
</html>
```

Comment: scrolled down??.. the image(or its container) is getting a scroll??.. or the window??..

Comment: @Vivek Chandra, the frame, the second picture is moved to the bottom of the first (scrolled down) with out possibility of viewing it.

Comment: Why are you using frames? They're technically deprecated...Can you post a jsfiddle example? I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: @elclanrs, easy way to go when you don't want to change the code on each HTML page when your not allowed using anything other than HTML...

Comment: 2 pictures... one 150px, other 600px... If screen is lower than the sum of 2, my other pictures is moved down and is not visible in my frame...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use min-width on the container of the images to 750px.It'll solve the problem.. and i agree with @elclanrs .. use div's to achieve this.. frames might not be the best way..

```
.logo_background{
min-width:760px;/* just to be sure adding an extra 10px */
}
```

Now,the container will have 760px no matter what size the window takes,so your pictures dont lose their location -- dont go out of view , you can still scroll right to see the logo's - both of them.. :)

Here's a fiddle for your problem -- http://jsfiddle.net/mvivekc/h4gVe/

Comment: style="min-width: 750px" in the body of logo or after making 2 pictures appear in div doesn't make my pictures to stay together.

Comment: lol.. its just a tool,you can replicate your problem there so that others can play with your code and provide you a better/quicker solution.. consider using it.. :)

Comment: I fiddle with notepad, firefox, and F5 :D

Answer (score 0):

Just style the logo frame to be a width of no less than 750 px.  I would think that would work.

Comment: Well, this could be. My logo frame is set to be 100% so maybe if I change it to higher width it might not do that (no problem since I hide the scroll bars). I will try this.

Comment: Leave the width at 100% and add also min-width of 750px